# How to make my class enabled to cast for Integer

Tags: java

I have a doubt on how to cast my class to `Integer`. Example:

```
public class IntegerField extends Field {
    private Integer value;
    public IntegerField(Integer value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int intValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

How can I make:

```
IntegerField a = new IntegerField(8);
Integer b = (Integer) a;
```

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot implement cast operation in Java like in C++

Comment: Really? Is there any simple way to work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't define your own conversion operators in Java. However, it's simple to add a method:

```
public class IntegerField extends Field {
    private Integer value;
    public IntegerField(Integer value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer toInteger() {
        return value;
    }
}

...

IntegerField a = new IntegerField(8);
Integer b = a.toInteger();
```

Why would you prefer a cast?

(Note that I've removed the `intValue` method which would throw an exception if `value` is null. The caller of `toInteger` can always convert to `int` if they *want* that behaviour.)

Comment: My main goal was to use IntegerField direct as an Integer, but I need some attributes attached to it so this is why I create the IntegerField. Judging by all answers I think there's no simple way to do this. I think I have to use your solution of having a toInteger method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Integer b = (Integer) a; --- incorrect becouse value is private, you must write a method to get value, Integer b = a.intValue();